# How to return ONE element based on class with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, getelementbyid

Say I have 3 divs

```
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="one two"></div>
<div class="one two three"></div>
<div class="one two"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
```

And in my js I have the following

```
var active = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
```

Which is returning all three divs. I only want the FIRST and LAST div to be called. How can this be achieved using jquery?

Comment: `var firstElement = active[0]`

Comment: I edit my answer. No this will not help. What if my elements were not in that order for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved easily with `javascript`. Just check if the `classList` of a `<div>` is equal to just the `class` you want to select. If it is not equal it means that the `classList` contains more than one class.

```js
function getValue()
{
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("one");
  
  for(var i=0; i < divs.length; i++)
  {
    if(divs[i].classList == 'one')
    {
        alert(divs[i].innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="one">hi</div>
<div class="one two">there</div>
<div class="one two three">coffee?</div>
<div class="one">not today?</div>

<input type="button" onclick="getValue()" value="click me" />
```

Comment: perfect exactly what I needed

Answer (score 2):

While you said *How can this be achieved using jquery?* you can use jquery like this

```js
//$('.one:first , .one:last').css('background' , 'red');  // if you just need first one and last one

$('.one:not(.two , .three)').css('background' , 'red');  // if you need the one class but not two or three
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one">1</div>
<div class="one two">2</div>
<div class="one two three">3</div>
<div class="one">1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, in this case:

```
// finding all elements whose 'class' attribute starts with
// 'one' and also ends with 'one'
document.querySelectorAll('[class^="one"][class$="one"]');
```

Or, more simply:

```
// finding all elements whose class attribute-value is
// equal to 'one'
document.querySelectorAll('[class="one"]');
```

References:

- [Attribute selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).
- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Using native selectors is always better than manually looping through class lists...

Comment: Agreed, but I'm (obviously) a little biased ;) but sometimes it's difficult after asking a question involving one approach (`getElementsByClassName()`) , getting an answer using that approach, and then changing to another approach that perhaps wasn't expected. Tool familiarity is a powerful thing! Also, I think the OP may have accepted the currently-accepted answer while I was writing this one. :)

Comment: @DavidThomas I agree. I've been downvoted for using `jQuery` before, so I did it the safe way, especially after I saw `document.getElem....`. Your answer is better, but mine is probably more understandable to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Check the jQuery equals selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/. Following three possibilities:

```
jQuery("[class='My class1']")

$$("[class='My class1']")

$("[class='My class1']").
```